# Testers not able to login into the Facebook integrated Android app

Tags: android, facebook

I have integrated  `Facebook`  in my  `Android`  app. I have added my friend as a `Tester` for the app. I think he has not accepted it and I find  `Pending`  near his name. When he tried to login with his facebook id, he couldn't login whereas I could login with my id as I am the  `Administrator`. I had never enabled or disabled the `Sandbox` mode and now also I am not able to enable or disable it. My `Single Sign On`  mode is on. Can anyone guide me how to fix it and should the person added as a tester accept the request and then only he will be able to test the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He'll go to developers.facebook.com/requests and accept the Tester role. Then he can login.